# Python & Kivy: Camera and Changing Screen

Tags: python, camera, kivy, screen

I want to build an app with Kivy in Python but I got some errors that I tried to solve many times but I can't.

I want to open a camera screen firstly. In screen, we will see our webcam screen and there will 2 buttons at the bottom (Play and Capture). While I pressing Play, webcam will be on and if I press Capture button, I want to take snapshot. I built the working code until here.

After pressing Capture button and taking snapshot, I want to change the screen in order to go 2nd screen and it will just show a basic Hello World sentence in black background.

Here it is my code, where is my fault? Can you fix it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import time

class CheckScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

Builder.load_string("""
ScreenManagement:
    CheckScreen:

<CameraClick@ScreenManager>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press:
            root.capture()
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'check'

<CheckScreen>:
    name: "check"
    Button:
        text: "Next Screen"
        font_size: 50
""")

class CameraClick(BoxLayout):

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")
        return CheckScreen

class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

When I'm running this code, it shows;

> AttributeError: 'CameraClick' object has no attribute 'manager'

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but your `CameraClick` class is defined in your `kv` code as extending `ScreenManager`, but in your `py` code `CameraClick` class is defined as extending `BoxLayout`. Your `py` code is probably taking precedence, so `CameraClick` does not extend `ScreenManager` and thus has no attribute `manager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple problems with your code. As John Anderson mentioned in the comments, you had one class inheriting from different classes in your py/kv files. You also had 2 screen managers - you should only need 1. I believe your CameraClick class should really only inherit `Screen` from kivy, not `ScreenManager` or `BoxLayout`. You can define a layout inside of the CameraClick class itself.

Your error was coming from the fact that you were trying to get the 'manager' attribute of your CameraClick class which you hadn't defined anywhere. To reference a screen manager (which it looks like is what you were trying to do) you must give the screen manager an 'id' and reference it that way (as you have with your Camera).

Another good practice you should use when working with a ScreenManager is to give your screens and id and name when you're adding the screens to the ScreenManager widget. e.g. instead of

```
ScreenManagement:
    CheckScreen:
```

Do

```
ScreenManagement:
    CheckScreen:
        name: "check_screen"
        id: check_screen
```

Another good practice is to load your `kv` code into a variable, and return that in your main app's `build` method.
And so forth. I've changed your code a bit and I think it should do what you expect now. Take the time to review it and compare to yours so you can see the differences, and let me know if it's not what you're looking for.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import time

class CheckScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CameraClickScreen(Screen):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))


GUI = Builder.load_string("""

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        CameraClickScreen:
            name: "camera_click_screen"
            id: camera_click_screen
        CheckScreen:
            name: "check_screen"
            id: check_screen



<CameraClickScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (640, 480)
            play: False
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Play'
            on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Capture'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press:
                root.capture()
                # root refers to <CameraClickScreen>
                # app refers to TestCamera, app.root refers to the GridLayout: at the top
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].transition.direction = 'left'
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].current = 'check_screen'

<CheckScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "Next Screen"
        font_size: 50
""")

class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI


TestCamera().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only missing part was when I click Play button, it didn't open the camera and also if I would press Capture button, it was taking empty screenshot.

If I change

`Label:
            text: "Camera:"
            id: camera
            resolution: (640, 480)
            play: False
`
with

`Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (640, 480)
            play: False
`

it works as I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh right, when I was debugging I didn't have access to a Camera so I was just playing with a Label instead. I'll update my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no problem with the code. To run the code on Android, you have to give it permission. Here is the code; you can add it on the top of your code:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA,Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

> **NOTE:** After importing the Android module, the code may give an “import error” while compiling on a desktop, but it will build and run successfully on Android.

Also, don't forget to change the code in the `buildozer.spec` file:

```
android.permissions = CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```